# How do I iterate through resource folder inside jar file?

Tags: java-me

In J2ME is there anything like

```
ResFolder resFolder = new ResFolder("/myFolder"); // or "/myfolder/*.png"
for (i=0; i<resFolder.count; i++] {
  img = Image.createImage(resFolder.fileName[i]);
}
```

?

I'm using a .txt with the name of the files to do that. Does anyone know if there's a more practical way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: I've seen this question before, and the answer has been no. I don't believe it's possible to traverse the res folder. Using a txt file is your best option.

Comment: Thank you! If so, I don't know if it's a superfluous or wonderful economy of resources from the java team.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options.

1.) A jar file is a Zip file, contents can be enumerated, e.g. here
[List Contents Of Zip File Example](https://www.java-examples.com/list-contents-zip-file-example)

2.) A resource(folder) is technically an URL, which does not provide enumeration. But you may generate an index as resource `/path/to/your/content/index.txt`, which lists the content/files. So, from that index you can compose the resource URLs and access them.

Latter option works for jar and file repositories.